# Editing commands to switch to threading macro in evil-cleverparens/clojure

Tags: emacs, evil-mode, paredit

I've been using emacs/evil/cider for a while and finally want to make the plunge into a paredit like environment. I'm trying evil-cleverparens, though imagine this concept applies to any sexp-editor/mode.

Say I have a nested sexp `(a (b (c d)))` and I want to switch it over to use a threading macro `(->> d c b a)`. What editing commands can I use to streamline this process?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in vanilla paredit-mode:

`(a (b (c| d)))`

C-M-t (transpose-sexps)

`(a (b (d| c)))`

C-M-u (paredit-backward-up)

`(a (b |(d c)))`

C-M-t (transpose-sexps)

`(a ((d c) |b))`

C-M-u (paredit-backward-up)

`(a |((d c) b))`

C-M-t (transpose-sexps)

`(((d c) b) |a)`

C-M-p (paredit-backward-down)

`(((d c) b|) a)`

C-M-p (paredit-backward-down)

`(((d c|) b) a)`

M-s (paredit-splice-sexp)

`((d c| b) a)`

M-s (paredit-splice-sexp)

`(d c| b a)`